# What are methods to play audio/video files from a tablet onto a media center?

Tags: remote-control, media-player

I need to have my kodi-based entertainment platform account for android tablets to play high definition media files (audio and video) located on the tablet. Kodi runs on an ARMv7 board, such as the [Orange Pi](http://orangepi.org) and is connected to a large screen (24-27 inches). So far the possibilities that I have encountered are:

- audio/video streaming
- Android screen casting (with audio)
- accessing the tablet through USB/Bluetooth/Wifi as a hard drive
- an audio/video sharing application (either existing or to be developed)

Note that the tablet is also to be used as a remote control for Kodi through Yatse – I've just discovered that app, I don't know its features thoroughly yet.

I'm not sure screen casting can occur with a non-android node however; for example, I have seen Android TV do support receiving media content from tablets and smart phones. As for streaming, I assume it would imply a high bandwidth usage. I know VLC can do that but I'd like to spare the user from any configuration/preparation manipulations. Finally I'm not sure any tablet can be shared as a disk drive, be it through USB, wireless or Bluetooth.

Does the above make sense? What possibilities are available along with pros and cons?

Comment: If you're already using Kodi at your Pi – why not doing the same on Android? See e.g. [DLNA server and client all-in-ones](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna#group_324) for some goodies in that area. You will notice an app called "Kodi" being top-ranked ;)

Comment: Sounds interesting indeed. Just that I have no clue how DLNA works :ashamed: ...

Comment: That explains. But that's not a topic suitable for this site. In short: an app can be a client, a server, a controller, or any combination of that. BubbleUPnP e.g. does all 3 parts. A controller can pick a file from a server, and tell another client to play it; this way I use BubbleUPnP to play stuff from my server on my stereo (or TV). Give BubbleUPnP a try, might spare you using two apps (and you can skip Yatse ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not sure I can skip Yatse though as there's no keyboard nor mouse attached to the media center so I do need a remote that also provides a virtual keyboard and Yatse does that.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! As I wasn't sure how you use Yatse, I've put the "might" :) Still, the combination "might" prove useful. Enjoy playing with DLNA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yatse is indeed a really nice app and allows you to stream any content from your phone to your Kodi enabled device. You probably have to buy the pro version.

Alternatively you could just install an (S)FTP or NFS server on your phone and add the remote drive in Kodi.

Comment: I didn't know Yatse could stream to the media center. I will investigate that, as I mentioned to @izzy.

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem lies in some missing background, so let me give you a starter:

[DLNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) was made for stuff like that. To put it simple, a DLNA network can have the following elements:

- **DLNA server:** stores media (audio, still pictures, video) to be accessed by …
- **DLNA client:** accesses DLNA server(s) and plays content available there
- **DLNA control points:** while not strictly needed, these can be quite useful. A DLNA control point can access DLNA servers and clients as well, to e.g. grab a movie and tell your TV to play it. The client (here: TV) must support being accessed by the control point; network enabled TVs and amplifiers usually do.

I'd recommend you taking a look at my list of [DLNA server and client all-in-ones](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna#group_324), especially at *BubbleUPnP* – which is what I use from time to time: using this app, I can access my media server (Kodi in your case), and play media on my TV (Samsung) and amplifier (Onkyo) just fine. In that list, you'll also find *Kodi* for Android: as you're already using that on your Pi, you might prefer something you're already familiar with.

Comment: I will definitely have a look at that and compare with @pluto's answer. Both suggestions seem quite interesting and I now have at least a concrete choice, thanks a lot again.

Comment: Yes, I just checked that: pluto is right, the paid version of *Yatse* can act as control point – so you might go with that and only have to use one app. And of course a [file server](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server) has additional advantages (you could use it to access your Android device's files from your PC).